# how can I display alert when user is nearby annotation?

Tags: annotations, mapkit, pins

I am trying to display an alert when user is nearby annotation
I have multiple annotation.

Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying - what code have you written so far?

Comment: I just add user location and a few annotations, but I have know idea how can I show an alert for example when the user is nearby 1 km from annotation.